# posting issues to Github repo via a Javascript ajax request

Tags: github, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to create issues in a Github repo via a Javascript client. My code is like so

```
const github = `https://api.github.com/repos/${owner}/${repo}/issues`;

const msg = JSON.stringify({
    "title": `problem with record id: ${recId}`,
    "body": "something is wrong in Houston",
    "assignee": "flooba",
    "milestone": 1,
    "labels": [
        "images"
    ]
});

const x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open('POST', github, true);
x.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (x.readyState == 4) {

        // show status message, all good
    }
};
x.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
x.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("username:password")); //**
x.send(msg);
```

[**] username and password are the creds for the :repo, naturally.

When I try the above code, I get http 422. Suggestions?

Note: In the actual working code, I will put the credentials on the server side and invoke the server side process from the web client.

Comment: Have you replaced `:owner` and `:repo` in your code?

Comment: Yes, of course :)